# How to set the function parameter in alias?

Tags: git, bash, github, alias

Here is my function to git push wordpress directory.

```
pushwp(){
cd /var/www/html/wp
git init
git add *
git commit -am  "$1"
git push -f origin master
}
```

pushwp function is in good status.

```
pushwp  "it is a test"
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /var/www/html/wp/.git/
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
Everything up-to-date
```

Now to assign the function with alias.

```
alias pushme='pushwp(){
cd /var/www/html/wp
git init
git add *
git commit -am  "$1"
git push -f origin master
}'
```

Let's try it.

```
pushme  "it is a test"
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"it is a test"'
```

How to fix the alias?

Comment: You already have a _function,_ why on earth would you wrap it in an alias? it makes no sense! just use the function. Unless you want a _git alias._

Comment: You don't. Aliases aren't functions.

Comment: Your alias only *defines* the function; it does not call it as well. You could make your alias define *and* call the function (`alias pushme='pushwp() {...}; pushwp '`), but as @gniourf_gniourf points out, there is little or no reason to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, you need to define and call your alias. But you don't need to here.

Make sure you don't initialize the repo each time you want to push it: the git init should be done only once and not part of that alias.

And you can use `git add .` instead of `git add *` (which relies on bash expansion)